# 'Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)' while creating my api service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  courseshine_redis:
    container_name: courseshine_redis
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}
    volumes:
      - courseshine_redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - internal

  courseshine_db:
    container_name: courseshine_db
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: courseshine_docker/development/courseshine_db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=${POSTGRES_DEV_DB},${POSTGRES_TEST_DB}
    ports:
      - ${COURSESHINE_DB_PORT}:${COURSESHINE_DB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - courseshine_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./courseshine_db:/dockerfile-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - internal

  courseshine_pgadmin:
    container_name: courseshine_pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.21
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - courseshine_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    depends_on:
      - courseshine_db
    networks:
      - internal

  courseshine_api: &api_base
    container_name: courseshine_api
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: courseshine_docker/development/courseshine_api/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ../../courseshine_api:/var/www/courseshine/courseshine_api
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - bundle_cache:/usr/local/bundle
    depends_on:
      - courseshine_redis
      - courseshine_db
    networks:
      - internal

  courseshine_ui:
    container_name: courseshine_ui
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: courseshine_docker/development/courseshine_ui/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ../../courseshine_ui:/var/www/courseshine_ui
    depends_on:
      - courseshine_api
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
volumes:
  courseshine_redis_data:
  courseshine_postgres_data:
  pgadmin:
  bundle_cache:
```

**my docerfile for courseshine_api service**

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs  libpq-dev postgresql-client && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APP_HOME /var/www/courseshine/courseshine_api

RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY ./courseshine_api/Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
COPY ./courseshine_api/Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --path vendor/cache
# Copy the main application.
COPY ./courseshine_api $APP_HOME 

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY ./courseshine_docker/development/courseshine_api/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by
# default.
CMD ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

set -e

rm -f $APP_HOME/tmp/pids/server.pid

exec "$@"

when i hit docker-compose up, the courseshine_api service is not stand and throw Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound). Why this problem occur and how to fix this ..

Comment: Since you're using `volumes:` to mount code over the application directory in the `courseshine_api` container, anything the Dockerfile does in that directory tree is lost.  In particular the `vendor/cache` directory in the image is hidden by the volume mount.  Does deleting that specific volume mount help?

Comment: no it does't work , same error persist .